# resolving appcompat_v7 error

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I am having a issue regarding the resolving of appcompat_v7...As mentioned on many answers i imported the jar file from the \sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\libs...
[image]

but the problem is under properties->android  i am getting a red cross next to appcompat_v7[image]

as mentioned on various answers i then clicked on add button here...but i get no library name

[image]

the library is installed as the import is working properly as can be seen here[image] the import shows no error..but my style.xml file in the res folder is showing the following error[image]

can somebody please tel me what i am doing wrong here..
also my SDK manager shows that my android support library is installed...
I am just new to android and cant figure out what I am doing wrong here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont import jar's from the appcompact-v7 library. You import the library itself in your workspace. Then you add the library into your project. In your project you can remove the **appcompact-v7** in red and add it again. That should solve the issue.

Comment: could you pls explain it a bit or provide a link hw to do tht?

Comment: @TilakRajSingh see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23019155/how-to-import-an-existing-android-library-project-into-eclipse-workspace

Answer (score 0):

Note also that:

1. You must have the latest versions of SDK Tools / Build Tools / Platform Tools. If you try this and it doesn't work, then go to the Android SDK Manager and make sure you have the latest versions of the required tools.
2. In case your project only requires API level 14 (Ice Cream Sandwich) & above, select API level 14 for "minimum required SDK" in the project wizard when you create a new project. Now the appcompat_v7 library will not be required for this project, and the application will use the native ActionBar class which is present in AOSP builds from ICS onwards.